# accessing EC2 instance from cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin

I should follow these instruction to connect to my EC2 instance with cygwin :

```
$ cd ~  
$ cp /cygdrive/c/Users/JohnSmith/Downloads/cs184-john-stanford-edu.pem .  
$ chgrp Users cs184-john-stanford-edu.pem  
$ chmod 0400 cs184-john-stanford-edu.pem  
$ ssh -i cs184-john-stanford-edu.pem \  
ubuntu@ec2-50-19-140-229.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

but when I type the second line with my credential is says:

```
-bash: cp/cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Downloads/provaedu.pem: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the `cygdrive` if you have your mount table set up correctly.

Try:

```
cp /c/Users/JohnSmith/Downloads/cs184-john-stanford-edu.pem .
```

With the following mount table:

```
$ mount
C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/projects on /projects type ntfs (binary)
C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```